# Two executables via gcc Makefile

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

Here is my Makefile:

```
# Makefile

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-ansi -Wall

prog1: prog1.o
prog2: prog2.o

clean:
   rm -f prog1.o prog2.o
```

Which works and creates a 'prog1' executable from prog1.c, but it does not build prog2 at all.  How would I make it do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `all` target and put it before both `prog1` and `prog2`:

```
all: prog1 prog2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `make prog2` to make prog2 seperately, or add a `all: prog1 prog2` rule to make both automatically.